# Nested enumerate lists and missing \item errors

Tags: enumerate, texstudio, enumitem

When using nested `enumerate` environments, I am using the following syntax :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*.]
\item A question
\stepcounter{enumi}
\begin{enumerate}[label*=\alph*.]
\item A subquestion.
\item Another subquestion.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

which works just fine and displays exactly what I expect:
[image]

However, with this other example,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*.]
\stepcounter{enumi}
\begin{enumerate}[label*=\alph*.]
\item A subquestion.
\item Another subquestion.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I have a `missing \item` error, despite of an output corresponding to my expectations.
What would be a correct way of proceeding in order to avoid such errors ?

And a related question (which would maybe deserve another topic): with TeXstudio, the second example does not display the PDF preview because of the compilation error, while with TeXmaker it does. Is there any way to display the PDF in case of (minor) compilation errors in TeXstudio ?

Comment: You just need at least one item in the outer list, before typesetting content or using a another list which in turn typesets some stuff. In my opinion, the subquestion number should coincide with the outer question number, the a), b) counting is quite good then.

Comment: I've deleted my answer since it was apparently of no use to you, lacking the features you requested but not specified

Comment: did you find an answer to this question? it's really bugging me as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a simple dummy item of no label `\item[] {}`, one can write this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

Some text ...    
\begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*.]
\item[] {}
\stepcounter{enumi}
\begin{enumerate}[label*=\alph*.]
\item A subquestion.
\item Another subquestion.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't this leave to much space above the inner list?

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I want. @ChristianHupfer : my complete document is by far more complex thant that and I've already added the necessary material to manage spaces.

Comment: @mvienney: Your design decision then ...

Comment: The space above the inner list can be controlled by setting `topsep=0pt`, for example, in the options for the outer list.